# Tenary operator within string.format

Tags: c#, string.format

In c#, string.format, are the arguments always computed?
The below code throws index out of bound exception - does that mean that the args are computed before the result of ternary operation?

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = {0, 1};
        int i = -1;
        var errstr = string.Format(i < 0 ? "Wrong Index" : "value - {0}", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code boils down to `string.Format("Wrong Index", a[-1])`. Can you guess which part of that is problematic?

Answer (score 4):

try just

```
var errstr = i < 0 ? "Wrong Index" : string.Format("value - {0}", a[i]);
```

> The below code throws index out of bound exception - does that mean that the args are computed before the result of ternary operation?

No, the ternary operator is applied to the *format string*, not the *argument*. Your arg is computed *every* time. In the `i<0` case it becomes

```
var errstr = string.Format("Wrong Index", a[-1]);
```

which throws an exception evaluating `a[-1]` even though it is not referenced in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `a[i]` the result will be `a[-1]` so the exception is correct.

```
  var errstr = string.Format(i < 0 ? "Wrong Index" : "value - {0}", a[i]);
```